# How to detect in git whether the new branch has a commit?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

What I require:

- `master` branch is the main branch.
- Now I create a branch `1-my-new-issue` from `master`.
- `master` has now moved ahead, it actually may or may not move ahead, it doesn't matter.
- I want to detect, whether my branch `1-my-new-issue` has any new commit.

To avoid this being a XY problem, why i want this:

- I am using GitlabCI
- Pipelines automatically run in a issue branch even though there is no new commit on the branch.
- I want to avoid running pipelines when there is no change to this branch from the point it was checked out from `master`.

From what I know gitlab ci provides no known way to do this, so I was thinking if I could detect it using `git` then I can simply skip the job.

Comment: You need to check whether `1-my-new-issue` is contained in `master`. If so, it has no new commits.